# Accessing Custom URL Params in Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails 4 application I have a url that is passing through an external service object ID (DocuSign object ID). I'm trying to access that ID that is in the URL's params in my controller to generate a subsequent URL.

My route:

```
resources :pledge, only: [:show, :update]
  resources :documents, only: [:show], param: :envelope_id
```

The link of the route in the view

```
<%= link_to "Click here", user_pledge_document_path(:envelope_id => @envelope_id), :target => "_blank" %>
```

An example of the URL in the browser

```
http://localhost:3000/users/3/pledges/117/documents/716726EF-8888-40B0-84D0-7AFD3CAB9291
```

Here is the controller where I am trying to access the envelope_id

```
# documents_controller.rb
def show
  envelope_id = params[:envelope_id]
  pp envelope_id
end
```

There is no output when I print the envelope_id variable to console. However, if I print something like the lender_id to console from the same URL and in the same controller action it works as expected.

How can I access the envelope_id in the URL params when I'm inside of the show controller action?

Comment: The entire params hash should be logged in your development.log file - from there it should be straightforward.

Comment: Is the variable stored in `params[:document_id]`? I'm not sure if the routes are setup properly.

Comment: from where you have find define route like this   resources :documents, only: [:show], param: :envelope_id , could you provide a reference.